# Access SQL: Calculating Percent Change between two rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to calculate the percentage change between two dates in Access.
The user inputs the start date, an end date and the desired percentage change. If the result matches the criteria it should return the name. 
Please note this is the dd/mm/yy format.

This is the table I have:

```
Name   | Payment | DateTime
John   | 53.00   | 06/01/18
Mike   | 23.16   | 12/07/18
Steve  | 31.28   | 21/03/18
John   | 58.30   | 22/04/18
```

For example, if the user inputs a start date of 01/01/18, an end date of 23/04/18, and a desired percentage change of 10 percent then it should return the name John.

Currently, this is the query I have:

```
SELECT Name

FROM UserPayments

WHERE DateTime >= '01/01/18' AND DateTime <= '23/04/18';
```

I would like to calculate the total percentage change for two entries. This should be the record date immediately after the first date and the date immediately before the second date.

I'm completely stuck on how to do this in Access (SQL). 
I think I need to use a join, but I have not done these before.

Comment: I don't really get the logic.  John doesn't have any data on those two dates.

Comment: @Gordon, the question calls for dates between (>= and <=, not =)
My question to the OP is do you only want to most recent two entries to be considered for each person, or if any of the entries for John show a 10% jump within the date range you want them included?

Comment: @user10292318 . . . Your description is still unclear.  What if John's numbers during the period were 5, 10, 7?  What is the percentage change?

Comment: I would like to calculate the total percentage change for two entries (the dates immediately after the and the date immediately before). The user inputs the percentage change. It is the how percentage change in price between the two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a `Users` table with a primary key of something like `UserID`, and that `UserID` should be used in the `UserPayments` table instead of the `Name` of the user.

Although it would by nice to use functions like `First` and `Last`, MS Access will not allow to use `ORDER BY` for sorting the details in a group defined by `GROUP BY`. Therefore, you will have to use subqueries to retrieve the two values for the percentage calculation. If you have a `Users` table like mentionned above and the `DateTime` value can be assumed to be unique per *User*, this could look like this:

```
SELECT Users.Name, 
 (SELECT TOP 1 Payment FROM UserPayments 
  WHERE UserID = Users.UserID AND DateTime Between #01/01/2018# And #04/23/2018# 
  ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
  /
 (SELECT TOP 1 Payment FROM UserPayments 
  WHERE UserID = Users.UserID AND DateTime Between #01/01/2018# And #04/23/2018#
  ORDER BY DateTime ASC)
  -1 AS PercentChange
FROM Users;
```

Be aware of rounding errors and format the result as a percentage.